# Pattern for multiple types of UI (Web, WPF, android) but single domain model

Tags: c#, android, wpf, mvvm, web

I have an application which has multiple UI Web, WPF, android. But I am a WPF developer. For WPF I know that MVVM pattern is best for WPF but for others I don't know.

I don't think I can use MVVM in Web and android application. How should I implement this so that same DomainModel can be used in all three UI application.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: I disagree that MVVM is WPF specific. You will find that many JavaScript developers also use the MVVM pattern. With your particular situation, can you design your system so that you have a web service that accesses a data store, and have your 3 UI applications consume the web service?

Comment: thanks for comment. You might be correct as I dont know about web applications.